# Gigabit Network card via USB slower than 100Mb onboard

Tags: networking, usb

I am using a netbook as a home server, with 10/100 Mbps onboard NIC and USB 2.0 ports.

Working well, but I am getting file transfer rates of max 12 MB/s in either direction (verifying with details in standard windows copy progress dialog).  As expected because of the 100 Mbps NIC.

By contrast, through a USB port to an external drive I can get over 20 MB/s.  So I figure the USB port is faster, and I can use it to get better transfer rates via a USB to Gigabit adapter.

I bought a D-Link DUB-1312, and it works, but now I am only getting max 5 MB/s, much worse than through the onboard Ethernet.

I have verified the adapter is working at Gigabit speed (through lights on the hub) so where is the bottleneck happening, and can I fix it?

Seems the whole process has been a waste of time, but what bothers me most is why the experience is not making sense with the specs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification for USB 2.0 has a data transfer rate of 480 Mbit/s (or about 40 Mbytes/s). So a data transfer rate of 20 MB/s to a external drive is reasonable (due to overhead).

Using an external ethernet connection will be slower than an internal card since the data needs to be converted from PC Bus (to USB bus) to ethernet line to destination. The extra conversion will slow down the overall data transfer rate.

Comment: Hi @LDC3, so you are saying that the conversion from PC Bus to USB Bus is the cause? (because the other factors are also present with the NIC).  In other words, this is the best I can expect from my new adapter, and the only way it can deliver anything higher than this, despite being a gigabit adapter, is if it used with a USB 3.0 port? (which it does support but my netbook doesn't have)

Comment: Essentially, yes. You do have the extra conversion along with acknowledge signals that slow down the data transfer. Pointing to a specific bottleneck is difficult due to the overhead involved in getting the data from point A (through C) to B. You would have a faster transfer rate with USB 3 (possibly up to your network speed, I don't know since I have no experience with USB 3).